# how do i limit prefetch_related in Django?

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-orm

Say I've got image objects with a manytomany relationship with tag objects.

now, I'm creating a search view to display images and the tags are displayed for each image, obviously the smart thing to do is to prefetch the tags for the images.

however I'm only displaying 15 images every time but I do have to evaluate the whole queryset in order to display how many results overall there are.
so I need to prefetch the tags **only** **for the first 15 elements**

If i prefetch the tags before slicing:

```
images = watson.filter(queryset, query).prefetch_related('tags')
amount = images.count()
images = images[:15]
```

this is very bad because there can be thousands of results and each result can have many tags.

but If I slice first:

```
images = watson.filter(queryset, query).prefetch_related('tags')[:15]
amount = images.count()
```

now I only prefetch tags for 15 results which is good however I can't count the results without making another query.

If i do this:

```
images = watson.filter(queryset, query)
amount = len(images)
images = images.prefetch_related('tags')[:15]
```

I still end up hitting the database twice because prefetch does a new db query.

**basically I need to hit the database once to get all the images, but only prefetch the tags for the first 15.**

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `count()` first, then do `prefetch_related()` and slice the queryset.

```
images = watson.filter(queryset, query)
amount = images.count()
images = images.prefetch_related('tags')[:15]
```

This will do one query for the count, one for the first 15 images, and one to prefetch the tags. Calling `count()` is better than `len()` because it won't fetch the images you don't need.

Comment: This example hits the database twice, once when count is called and again when prefetch_related is called.

Comment: Is the `count()` causing poor performance? If not, I think that worrying about it is a case of premature optimisation. I'm not sure whether fetching all results, and only prefetching the first 15 would be noticeably faster anyway; calling `count()` is more efficient than `len()` for large queries, because the queryset is not loaded into memory.

Comment: It's annoying to have to hit the database twice for one set of images because I can't prefetch for only 15. Why is this premature optimization? I'm looking to optimize.. using count instead of len() is a valid correction, but thats not what this question is

Comment: My feeling is that it's premature optimisation because the time saved by preventing one count query will not be worth the time spent achieving it, and might complicate the code. If you're looking to optimize then go for it, if you find a nice way to do it then please post it here. As I was trying to explain before, it might be more efficient to fetch 15 results and do an additional count, rather than fetching all 1000 results to prevent the count. You would have to measure to find out.